# What does the # symbol after an IP address mean?

Tags: dns, nslookup

I resolved an IP address from a URL using [nslookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup) and noticed the following:

```
nslookup https://example.com

Server 192.168.3.214

Address 192.168.3.214#53
```

What does the #53 at the end mean?

Comment: Why are you running nslookup with "https://" ?

Comment: nslookup is to look for a domain name using your local DNS (usually, that one defaults to global DNSes for "outside of your own local list" domain names). You should just do :   `nslookup  domainname` (here:  `nslookup example.com` ).  note that `www.example.com` may resolve differently than `mail.example.com` or other subdomains of example.com

Answer (score 33):

#53 refers to port 53, the standard port for DNS.

Comment: It should be noticed that this is not "standard" notation. More often than not, ports are specified using `:`, for example `127.0.0.1:443`. It seems to be a quirk in nslookup.

Comment: `nslookup` is a very old tool, before there was any convention for this notation.

Comment: @MechMK1 The answer used to say that; not sure why it doesn't any more.

Comment: @MechMK1 `nslookup` is part of `bind`, which is ancient, having started in the 80s at Berkeley.

Comment: @wizzwizz O edited it out of my answer because I initially overlooked the "nslookup" line, so I was speculating a bit. When I saw nslookup with wring syntax I modified my answer because I became sure of what #53 was but was no longer convinced that the # was nonstandard as that tool is ubiquitous, and arguably created the standard. I did not, however know it predated standard ":" notation - and wondered if it specifically implied UDP or something obscure like that.

Comment: It's probably a better notation, now that a colon is used for different purposes in IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

In any event, the Address...#53 line refers to the server, rather than being an answer to the resolution request. Running the command on- as others have observed- an elderly server:

```
$ nslookup https://example.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find https://example.com: NXDOMAIN

$ nslookup example.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.com
Address: 93.184.216.34
```

There is obviously scope for confusion here because of # being used for anchors inside web pages. However OP should have taken that error message to heart and wondered what else wasn't working as he expected :-)